# Where is the mongodb concurrent connection limit in parse-server?

Tags: mongodb, promise, parse-server

I have a scenario where I'm trying to do a lot of things concurrently against mongodb through parse-server.  Currently I can successfully evaluate ~1000 concurrent promises using Parse.Promise.when() which does operations against mongodb.

The strange thing is, on the database server, I'm only seeing around 5 concurrent connections.  At this stage, I'm not even sure if all 5 of those connections are from this app.

Looking at the source code, I can see these bits of parse-server talk to each other:
  parse-server.RestQuery.runFind
calls:
  parse-server.Controllers.DatabaseController.find
which in turn calls:
  parse-server.Adapters.Storage.MongoStorageAdapter.find
which in turn calls:
  mongodb.collections.find

This is as far as my mainly Java knowledge got me.  What I was hoping to find is the code responsible for making the tcp connection to our mongodb server and see how these pools of connections are managed.

I realise most of javascript is single threaded.  What I also understand is that the http part of javascript is multi-threaded, i.e. you can make multiple simultaneous connections without your javascript code execution being blocked.  And when the responses to those http requests come back, the javascript in the associated callback function will be executed.

What I don't know is whether the whether the mongodb parts of the javascript is also multi-threaded.  I'm guessing they should be as the mongodb nodejs code is simply making tcp calls similar to what the http parts of the nodejs javascript engine is doing.

Can someone confirm any of this or better yet tell me where the config that creates this bottle neck is.  Thanks.

Comment: have you got anywhere with this ?

Comment: Hey, any update on that?